# Text under line

Tags: text, underline

**My MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{colback=white,colframe=white,comment style=
{frame hidden,scale=2.1}, comment only, pdf comment, freeze pdf, compilable listing, run pdflatex,}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,soul}
\usepackage{soulpos}
\ulposdef{\ulnumaux}{%
$\underset{\saveulnum}{\rule[-.7ex]{\ulwidth}{.4pt}}$}
\newcommand{\ulnum}[2]{\def\saveulnum{#1}%
\ulnumaux{#2}}
\begin{document}
text text \ulnum{\text{(some text)}}{This is short text} text text 
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

**Produces:**

[image]

**But have to**

[image]

***So, what am I doing wrong?***

Comment: I'm not sure that `soulpos` is the right tool for obtaining that result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Happy New Year!

- Your MWE is (at least) very unusual ...
- If you like to reproduce the second image, the simplest way -- according to my opinion, but I may be wrong -- is use `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{} c @{}}
This is short text  \\  \hline
(some text) 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
After your edit of question seems, that you like this table to be in middle of the text:

[image]

For this only small change to proposed solution is needed:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
some text \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} c @{}} % <---
This is short text  \\  \hline
(some text)
\end{tabular} more text \lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

Is now answer more close to what you after?

Comment: Happy New Year! @Zarko, Thank You for your answer, but I'm afraid You are a bit wrong , I changed my MWE please look again.

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh, sorry, I wasn't  wrong. Your question was unclear. I will look in your question edition ASAP.

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh, see addendum to answer. Does it do what you after?

Comment: Yes, thank You very much. Also I will make a macro (or whatever it's called) using ```\newcommand``` for more convenient usage. Thanks

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh, defining a new command (macro) is way to go!

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach using the lua-ul (more robust than soul, but requires lualatex) and stackengine packages:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[varwidth=6cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{lua-ul}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand{\mystack}[2]{%
  \stackunder[1pt]{\underLine{#2}}{\tiny (#1)}%
}

\begin{document}
text text \mystack{some text}{This is short text} text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You for the answer, but I use pdfLaTeX instead of lualatex, so unfortunately it does not work in my project. However, thank You for your help, it is also a great solution!